# Where statement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, where-clause

How can I use where statement in pandas with two or more criteria?

For example, I have price and currency columns with 3 currencies($, EUR, YUAN). I want to create a unique price column in $ with `where` statement.

```
df['new_price'] = df.price.where(df.currency=='$', df.price*0.14)
```

but I can't do this for YUAN either.

Comment: You can nest conditions with `np.where()`

Comment: ```map``` looks like a good choice here

Answer (score 2):

Look into `select` from numpy, its simple

```
import numpy as np

df['new_price'] = np.select([df.currency=='$', df.currency=='YUAN'], 
                            [df.price*0.14, df.price*2], 
                            default=df.price)
```

The logic:

```
np.select( [condition1, condition2, condition3, ...]
           [result_if_cond1_is_true, result_if_cond2_is_true, ...] # same number of results as conditions
           default=if_no_condition_is_satisfied)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where()` as an alternative and nest conditions in the `false` statement:

```
df['new_price'] = np.where(df['currency'] == '$',df['price']*0.14,
                            np.where(df['currency'] =='EUR', 
                                     df['price']*1,
                                     df['price']*2))
```

So it checks if the currency is `$` if it's not, then it checks for `EUR`, if it's not, it has to be `YUAN`

Comment: "ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given" That error occured for last line

Comment: nested where should be avoided in favour of the clearer np select